# Is it ok to delete object allocated in python from c++?

Tags: c++, python, api

In my program I manage references to python objects in C++. I.e. all my classes are derived from class Referenced, which contains pointer to corresponding python object.

```c
class Referenced
{
public:
    unsigned use_count() const
    { 
        return selfptr->ob_refcnt;
    }

    void add_ref() const
    {
        Py_INCREF(selfptr);
    }

    void remove_ref() const
    {
        Py_DECREF(selfptr);
    }

    PyObject* selfptr;
};
```

I use intrusive_ptr to hold objects derived from Referenced. This allows me to easily keep references to required python objects in C++ and access them whether necessary. But my program crashes (only in windows howewer) when python object is going to be deleted from C++, i.e. when I call Py_DECREF(selfptr), whether selfptr->ob_refcnt == 1. **Is this approach OK?**

---

**Upd:** I finally figured out problem in my program. It wasn't related directly to object removal. To check the initial question I've implemented simple extension module remembering reference to python object and releasing it on demand. Here is it:

```c
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* myObj;

static PyObject* acquirePythonObject(PyObject* self, PyObject* obj)
{
    printf("trying to acquire python object %p, refcount = %d\n", obj, obj->ob_refcnt);
    myObj = obj;
    Py_INCREF(myObj);
    printf("reference acquired\n");
    return Py_True;
}

static PyObject* freePythonObject(PyObject*, PyObject*)
{
    printf("trying to free python object %p, refcount = %d\n", myObj, myObj->ob_refcnt);
    Py_DECREF(myObj);
    printf("reference removed\n");
    return Py_True;
}

static PyMethodDef moduleMethods[] =
{
    {"acquirePythonObject", acquirePythonObject, METH_O, "hold reference to python object."},
    {"freePythonObject", freePythonObject, METH_NOARGS, "free reference to python object."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initmodule(void)
{
    Py_InitModule("module", moduleMethods);
}
```

And python script:

```
import module

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print "Foo is created"

    def __deinit__(self):
        print "Foo is destroyed"

def acquireFoo():
    foo = Foo()
    module.acquirePythonObject(foo)

def freeFoo():
    module.freePythonObject()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    acquireFoo()
    freeFoo()
```

Sample runs seamlessly in windows and linux. Below is the output.

```
Foo is created
trying to acquire python object 0x7fa19fbefd40, refcount = 2
reference acquired
trying to free python object 0x7fa19fbefd40, refcount = 1
Foo is destoryed
reference removed
```

Comment: Note that under windows there are some circumstances where allocating in one dll and deallocating in another will break things. I don't know which, but it might be worth checking, this smells a bit like it could be in your case. Note that this is a problem on poor windows implementations, and not a general problem with c++/pythong.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I feel the same way, but if I understood correctly python itself manages heap via c api functions (http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html), so allocation/deallocation calls should fall in the same dll.

Comment: not if python is linked to a different version of the C runtime than your C++ code is.

Comment: @PlasmaHH still not understood. If I call Py_DECREF I get into python_27.dll, so if it call free somewhere it should access function from c runtime against which python27.dll is linked. Just what I need. Am I not right?

Comment: When you call free somewhere, it calls the free function of whatever dll you are currently in.

Comment: With regards to the above issued: allocation and freeing in Python go throught the object's allocator and deallocator, defined by pointers in the `PyTypeObject` structure.  If they both point into the same DLL, there should be no problem.  (If you've linked correctly, there should be no problem either.)

Comment: @PlasmaHH If you've linked correctly, there is only one `free` function, in the dynamically linked C runtime library.  But of course, Python doesn't call the `free` function directly; it calls the deallocation function specified for that type.  Which will always point to the same function, in the same DLL.

Comment: I think every library which can create objects (factory) should also give you a method/way to dispose/free them (control of the object lifetime) if they don't do it themselfes - especially if you interop between different languages. Because some things might break if different memory managers are used in the background.

Comment: Could this be a threading issue? Are you trying to free the object in a different thread to the python main thread?

Comment: @jleahy program is single threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this approach OK?

Basically, but ...

- I don't see any guarantee that `add_ref`/`remove_ref` are called the correct number of times (using RAII would automate this - maybe that's what your intrusive_ptr does?)
- if you *do* try to `remove_ref` too many times, I'm not sure what Python guarantees. If you set `selfptr = NULL` when you know the refcount is going from 1 -> 0, you could catch this

  - either by crashing hard, or by checking explicitly, or by using `Py_XDECREF`
  - even better, just use `Py_CLEAR` instead

And finally ... do you have any crash dump or diagnostic info?

Comment: 1) yes, intrusive_ptr ensures RAII, I use one similar to boost::intrusive_ptr (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) 2) I have safety checks in Referenced class, just removed them to increase readability.

Comment: I have finally found the problem, crash was caused by other 3rdParty module, it was triggered by object destruction. Though I spent a lot of time figuring it, even wrote a small demo releasing python object in cpp. I'll put it here when I get home and verify it in linux.